# what approach I should use for external access to Cassandra running inside kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, emr

I have a StatefulSet Cassandra deployment that works great for services deployed to Kubernetes with namespace access, but I also have an ETL job that runs in EMR and needs to load data into that Cassandra cluster.

What would be the main approach/Kubernetes way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options.

Simple one is you can create the server with Type: NodePort, with this you can connect server with Node IP Address:PortNumber.

Second option is you can create the Ingress Load Balancer and connect to Cassandra cluster.

Comment: I think I can use a load balancer then make sure I don't use the token aware option from the connection point.  This will require some code change as that was hard coded and never configed out.  I'll have to see if I can get that change into the codebase next week.